# Why can I log into wp-login.php and not wp-admin.php?

Tags: wp-admin, login, wp-login-form

I have recently changed the config.php file in Wordpress in my FTP because the URL was wrong
( I did it with `define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.myyyysite.com'); define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.myyyysite.com');`.

Now I still cannot log into [www.myyyysite.com/wp-admin.php](http://www.myyyysite.com/wp-admin.php) but [www.myyyysite.com/wp-login.php](http://www.myyyysite.com/wp-login.php) works. Are there any problems that it **only works** for **the wp-login.php** and **not wp-admin.php**? I am just lucky that I could again log into my website, since I've tried also changing the url in the database but only the Wordpress config file worked.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: There is no wp-admin.php...

Answer (score 2):

Because **there is no `wp-admin.php` file in WordPress**:

[image]

You shouldn't be able to login via `wp-admin.php`, it should not exist!

Be extremely suspicious of this file, you may have been **hacked**, and have likely leaked your details to an attacker.

Comment: Hi how can I understand this? is wp-login.php not the right way to log into my Wordpress account?

Comment: Yes! You're supposed to use `wp-login.php` to login, but there is no `wp-admin.php` file in WordPress. If you have a `wp-admin.php` file then something has gone terribly wrong. `wp-admin.php` doesn't work because it's not supposed to exist.